# javascript post django form gives csrf error

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I have a html form like:

```
<form id="comment" action="{% url "url_name" ur.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <textarea required="required" maxlength="255" rows="4" class="form-control" name="comment">
    </textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_comment(event)">Comment</button>
</form>
```

It is a html form and not `django's` form.

Here I have included `csrf token` in the form. I  have post this form form javascript and now it gives me `csrf verification failed` error.

What am I missing here ? Is it mandatory to create form from django' form class to use csrf token ?

Need help

My js looks like:

```
function add_comment(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    var form = document.getElementById('comment')

    var url = form.action
    var method = form.method

    var form_data = new FormData(form)

    fetch(url, {method: method, body: form_data})

}
```

and I am just rendering a template from my django view

When I see request network, csrf token and comment are passed as request payload ..

Comment: give us your javascript code, and the views..

Comment: @SancaKembang I have updated the question

Comment: The problem you've got relates to the CSRF token not being passed as part of the form submission. I'm not overly familiar with fetch as I've always used AJAX, but this is where you're going wrong. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/30) suggests that you have to include the credentials, so that the CSRF cookie is sent with the request.

```
fetch(url, {method: method, body: form_data, credentials: 'include'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using AJAX to post the form. When posting forms with Django using AJAX you need to add the following to your Javascript before submitting the AJAX request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
        return cookieValue;
        }
        if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
            // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    } 
});
```

More info can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax